# how to Solve Windows 8 app Certification Test using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows, performance

I got some problem with windows 8 certification test . The problem is

> Bytecode generation Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected
>   the following errors: This package has JavaScript syntax or other
>   problems. (0x80040154) Impact if not fixed: As a performance
>   optimization to accelerate JavaScript execution time, JavaScript files
>   ending in the ".js" extension generate bytecode when the app is
>   deployed. This optimization significantly improves start-up and
>   ongoing execution times for JavaScript. How to fix: You may need
>   consider one or more of these steps to fix the issue:
>   - Ensure that event logging is enabled
>   - All JavaScript files are syntactically valid; otherwise exclude the respective files from the package
>   - Please note that you should uninstall all previous versions of the app before deploying Otherwise exclude the respective files from the
>   package.

my app using JavaScript and grid template from VS 2012.

can anyone help me to solve this problem?
i've tried several methods from 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/41a17586-581e-4845-be2a-d4c2b2570846/this-package-has-javascript-syntax-or-other-problems-0x80040154

and

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/15dd7c1c-c373-4f0c-93e5-9b0f9351f6ef/bug-appverifier-chokes-on-javascript-regexp

still can't solve my problem ?
is't any other method to solve this problem ? thanks before :D

sorry for bad english :D